# subdirectory on my domain gets 404 on some computers

Tags: http-status-code-404, vps

Im having a problem where this link
On some computers so far only in the state of NJ the webpage flashes goes away and a 404 error comes up
So far we have
1) Cleared the cache, cookies ect
2) Changed the subdirectory to where it has no caps, I went to norton safeweb and put a verification html up and norton doesnt recognize caps apparently, i felt it might be anti virus connected
3) so far the people having trouble have IE , i have run it on IE,Chrome,Safari,Firefox here in NJ with no isses
My next step is to physically travel to the trouble location and see if its the ISP

Does anyone have and ideas?

Below is the link which leads to a testing database which is fully functional except its a sandbox site

https://www.simplifiedchurch.net/sc/6e5aeb277a218704ef3ce9d37a211fa5cc/index.php?db=cXdkOFJsTlNSOElsUTRWN3d1WHNkRm5tYnVFZ203ZEVxcGhlMTY2dHJaYz0=

so far today it has been tested in texas, canada, north carolina and louisiana with no issues

Answer (score 0):

just an fyi  for someone else, it looks like 1 include was not loading (missing file) I created a custom 404 that emails me $_SERVER in the event of a 404 which is  the way i tracked it down